# Интеграция StyleCop.Analyzers в GitLab

Tags: c#, gitlab, gitlab-ci, static-analysis

У меня есь приложение на C# (.NET Core 3.1) и я использую в нём пакет StyleCop.Analyzers для статического анализа кода и вывода сообщений о найденных проблемах в кодовой базе. Анализ происходит "в фоне" при редактировании кода. Вопрос: можно ли интегрировать статический анализ с помощью этого пакета в пайплайн Gitlab? Чтобы найденные ошибки роняли пайплайн?

Comment: В тимсити точно можно [через шаг MSBuild сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6370278/5752652), наверное и в gitlab получится.

Comment: [Custom Analyzers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/analyzers.html#custom-analyzers)

Comment: да, можно, аналицаторы запускаются при билде, поэтому они должны отображаться в логах, просто поставьте, чтобы все Warning воспринимались как ошибки и крешили билд